# Expected RBRACE at line 64, col30

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand what is wrong. The css still does its job but I still get this error. I use Dreamweaver btw. I do not get an error if I remove this part.

```
.video-preview-description{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr; (HERE IS LINE 64)
}
```

Comment: Wha's the error?

Comment: It is the titile, "Expected RBRACE at line 64, col30"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver-discussions/expected-rbrace-at-line-4-col-2-is-this-error-a-bug/td-p/10547718

It might be a bug in dreamweaver

Comment: Yes you are right. Fr works just fine on Dreamweaver but still displays an error when used.